# unserialize() value insert with serialize() of database.?

Tags: php, database, arrays, serialization, foreach

i insert in database values (array) with use function `serialize()`, how can echo they with `unserialize()` in tag `<ul><li>...`?

i have in database this: `a:6:{i:0;s:15:"Coffee";i:1;s:14:"Satellite";i:2;s:11:"Game Notes";i:3;s:14:"Internet";i:4;s:10:"Pool";i:5;s:0:"";}`

> **LIKE:**
>
> - Coffee
> - Game Notes
> - Internet
> - Pool

Comment: Storing such a language dependent data in a database is not a good idea. If you want to migrate to JSP, ASP, etc. from PHP, you have to find a way to convert those data. Also it's quite cumbersome to find data within serialized array/object using SELECT queries. The best solution to have them in a normalized table structure; or at least use json_encode() since there's a high change that other languages support a way to decode a JSON string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `unserialize()`, as you said, with a `foreach()` loop, like this:

```
$arr = unserialize($dbString);

echo "<ul>";

foreach($arr as $key => $val)
{
    echo "<li>$val</li>";
}

echo "</ul>";
```

This will echo a list containing `value` because `foreach()` iterates through the `unserialize()`d array, as you have specified in your question.

The `$key => $part` is the icing on the cake for `foreach()`; if you want the get the array key, simply reference `$key`. If you want the data for that key, use `$val`.

---

If you want to echo just one element (your example is `Internet`), just don't use a loop and reference it by key (integer):

```
$arr = unserialize($dbString);

echo $arr[2];
```

This `echo`s the third element in the array on it's own.

Comment: if want only echo `Internet`, how is it?

Comment: Please answer the above question with example

Comment: There's a great function in PHP, which is print_r(). You can use it to print any kind of a data structure. Just check the output of print_r(unserialize($dbString)) and you'll definitely get a clue to get "Internet" printed.

Comment: @Emma See my edits. Can you edit your original question to show the PHP array using `print_r()` as Amil says?

Answer (score 0):

### Original question

Unserialize the data and loop over it printing it out. Notice that I have also added in checks to see that we are getting back an array and that it contains something before looping over it.

```
$data = unserialize($row['like']);
if(is_array($data) and count($data)) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($like as $value) {
        echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

### Internet

I think this is what you are asking for. To only echo out the value if its `Internet`.

```
$data = unserialize($row['like']);
if(is_array($data) and count($data)) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($like as $value) {
        if('Internet' != $value) {
            continue;
        }
        echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

### JSON

If you can I would stop using serialize and use json_encode instead. It is easier to encode and decode in more programming languages and it is easier to edit by humans should you need to update the DB directly.

Comment: if want only echo `Internet`, how is it? (Please answer the question with example)